# In django view, retrieve a cookie set by javascript

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, cookies

I have this method that sets a cookie:

```
var setCookie = function (name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
};
```

and here is how I use it to store an array of IDs in cookie:

```
var json_str = JSON.stringify($scope.arrayOfIDs);
setCookie('ids', json_str, 1);
```

It works just fine, taking a look at the `Resources` in Chrome gave me this:

```
['415', '234']
```

just how I want it to.

However, I cannot seem to access this array in django view:

```
print(request.COOKIES['ids'])
```

this is giving me ``, an empty string.

How can I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

my view file:

```
def items(request, category):
    print(request.COOKIES['ids'])
    # rest of the method
```

Comment: At what point are you checking the value in Django? Remember you actually have to make a request after setting the cookie for it to be sent to the server. What is the context for that last snippet?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I am checking it at the beginning of the view, right after declaration. I posted an update. I will post more if needed. Thanks

Comment: OK but what is calling that view? Are you doing it from JS? Where does the call come, in relation to that `setCookie` function?

Comment: No, I am not calling it from JS. This view is called when a user clicks on a category label. The view then returns a list of items belonging to that category. I thought that `cookies` is like a database, where I can store things from anywhere and access those things from anywhere else, can't I?

Comment: @JohnyStark why don't you do a GET with those `ids` values to your `a list of items belonging to that category` ? You could do it like this: `GET http://yoursite.com/?category=1&category=4&category=5`